# Emacs: cursor position inside parenthesis

Tags: emacs

In Emacs, I want to achieve an IDE-like behaviour with parenthesis block and cursor position. That is, when I type, for example, `int main() { RET`, it should expand to

```
int main() {
   I <- cursor position
}
```

I've installed smartparens plugin to automatically insert pairs, but it doesn't deal with the cursor:

```
int main() {
I <- cursor position}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Drew pointed out `electric-indent-mode`, I've looked up different electric-modes in Emacs and figured out that `electric-pair-mode` fits exactly my needs.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [Yasnippets](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet), a template system for Emacs which comes with a lot of templates preinstalled. In your case:

`main`<kbd>TAB</kbd>

will expand to:

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  CURSOR
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you request is already the case in Emacs, starting with release 24.4.

You can enable the behavior by turning on `electric-indent-mode`, if it is not already enabled by default (Emacs 24.4 or later).  Put this in your init file to enable the mode:

```
(when (fboundp 'electric-indent-mode) (electric-indent-mode 1))
```

However, you need at least Emacs release 24.1 to use `electric-indent-mode`.  It is not available in older releases.